# Creating a directory called 'con'

Tags: ruby, windows, directory

In the Ruby console, whenever I try to make a folder 'con', I get the following error:

```
> FileUtils.mkdir_p('con/')

Errno::ENOTDIR: Not a directory - con
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from (irb):21
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/irb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

It does not happen for other names.

Why does this happen?

I use Ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: No. I want to make the directory relative to the current one.

Comment: The action you tried and the error you got a bit confusing to me.. Because you are trying to create a directory and the error is saying, *this is not a directory* -- Is not this a so *confusing* ?

Comment: Can you do this `FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{__dir_}"/con/")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're using Windows.

In Windows, `con` is a reserved name for device (`console`). You cannot use that as a direcotry/file name.

See [MS-DOS Device Driver Names Cannot be Used as File Names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74496/en-us).

Comment: What you said, may be *true*, but in this case, I expect the error as **EACCES(*Simply, file permissions don't let you do the open() you requested*)**, why the OP mentioned error constant **ENOTDIR(*Any system call that expects a directory and doesn't get one will complain with this.*)** then ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, BTW, why do you think `mkdir_p` call `open()` ?

Comment: No... I am trying to read the description of those constants from this [link](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/errors.html). Because `Errno::ENOTDIR::Errno` gives `20` in my *openSUSE13.1*

Comment: @ArupRakshit, `Errno::ENOTDIR::Errno` in Ruby 2.0.0 + Windows 7 also gives `20`.

Comment: Yes, now the point is, the description of the message is saying, *Any system call that expects a directory and doesn't get one will complain with this* -- that means `mkdir_p` expected a *directory*, but it didn't get, so it throws an error. In such condition, how the *device files come into picture* - I am not getting this.

Comment: Humm... I saw, Anyway this scenario is a bit confusing to me. I don't have windows, so I can't try also. Thanks for comments.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Because these directory names are disallowed by Windows, it makes sense that a path containing a disallowed directory name is not a directory.

Comment: @Maarten Does this `FileUtils.mkdir_p('foo/')` work ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yeah. But `FileUtils.mkdir_p('con/foo/')` won't. **BTW:** the same error occurs if the length of the absolute path is longer than [the max path length in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) (260).

Comment: @Maarten Nice to hear back.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The folder `con` is an system-folder, you can't create this folder, delete this folder or save files in it, or read files from it,because `con` is a simulated device for the cmd. In the `Safe Mode` you can create this folder. Ther are some other folder-names like `con`.